# Join a list of integers

Tags: python

The problem : Design an algorithm to convert a string to an integer:

My approach:

```
string = '1221'
dictionary = {'1':1,'2':2}

string2 = [dictionary[w] for w in string] 

print "".join(string2)
```

This code won't work because (apparently) join() is a string function. How do I join the elements of the list if they are all integers?
(Can't use str() and int())

Comment: What is the purpose of the dictionary? Hint: You need to output a number, not a string. Hint2: Use `+` for addition

Comment: Loop over the string2 multiplying each element by `10**(len(string2)-i-1)` then sum, basic maths.

Comment: The dictionary is for maintaining numerical equivalent of string values. @cricket_007

Comment: You can use `ord()` to also get an integer value from a character

Comment: You never needed to join a list of ints or have a dictionary. You've essentially tried to do `''.join(list(string))` here

Comment: I was curious to see if there was something similar for list of integers. Also, I was not looking for an algorithm,(the edit misses the point of the question).

Comment: Sorry, Could you explain better? if your dictionary is really `{'1':1,'2':2}`` you can simply use `str()` (integer -> string) or `int()` (string -> integer). Also, I don't use python 2, but you can print a list without using this `.join()` simply use `*yourlist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use addition and multiplication to achieve this.

```
s = '1234'
ans = 0

for c in s:
    ans = ans*10 + ord(c)-ord('0')

print(ans)
```

This method will work because 1234 = ((1 * 10 + 2) * 10 + 3) * 10 + 4.

As '0' ~ '9' are consecutive in ascii, so we can use `ord(c)-ord('0')` to get the value of the digit.

#### EDIT

It's the same if you want to get the int from `string2`

```
string = '1221'
dictionary = {'1': 1, '2': 2}
string2 = [dictionary[w] for w in string]
ans = 0

for x in string2:
    ans = ans*10 + x

print(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you. But the question asked if there was a way to get to the answer from `string2` in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
def atoi(s): # ASCII to Integer, a "traditional" name for such function
    return sum(10**(len(s)-p-1) * (ord(x) - ord('0')) for p,x in enumerate(s))

atoi("123")
#123
```

Answer (score 0):

the int function will convert a string to integers if each character is a numeric character

```
int('1221')
```